# How can I make my tableview enter editing mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

for some reason I can't get my tableview to enter editing mode. It's a little harder than it might seem because I'm using some open source code to make a calendar (iCal esque) with a tableview under it, and it's not quite as straightforward as just using a regular tableview.

Basically, I have two classes. One (let's say Class A) is a UIViewController and the other (Class B) is that viewController's datasource and tableview delegate. In Class B, I've implemented

`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

which works fine, but if I put an edit nav bar item in Class A (the view controller), nothing happens. Am I forgetting certain protocols, or certain special methods that I need to write? Thanks for any help, and apologies if I'm missing something, I'm just learning to work with other people's code.

EDIT:

I just implemented this code in Class A (the view controller)

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate {
    self.tableView.editing = editing;
}
```

And that makes the editing circle come up, but it is not animated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost have it already.  Call super too.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animate];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animate];
}
```